# Mock ajax call with Jest

Tags: jquery, ajax, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

Can I get stub json response from ajax call?

```
$.ajax(
    options,
    success: function(data){
        ...
    },
    error: function(data){
        ...
    }
)
```

I tried, but got no luck.

```
$.ajax = jest.fn().mockImplementation((options) => {
    let instance = {
        done: (fn) => {
            if (options.success) fn("test passed");
            return instance;
        },
        fail: (fn) => {
            if (!options.success) fn("test failed");
            return instance;
        },
    };
    return instance;
});
```

I got the error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBe' of undefined

  37 |     )
  38 |
> 39 |     expect(response.toBe());
      |                     ^
  40 | });
  41 |
```

Ajax function seems to be replaced to the mock.

What did I miss?

JQuery: 1.11.3
Jest: 24.9.0

Comment: What do you get? Add more details

Comment: @slideshowp2 Thank you for reply. I added the detail to the question.

Comment: How did you execute the ajax call?

Comment: Do you mean, this?
`
$.ajax(
    options,
    success: function(data){
        ...
    },
    error: function(data){
        ...
    }
)
`